# How to set maxDate=28 for each month in jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

i want to select 28 as maximum date for each month and current date time as minDate. so i have done like below
my code is:

```
   var dateToday = new Date(); 
   $("#date1_live").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
                    showAnim:'slideDown',
                    dateFormat:'dd M yy',
                    minDate: dateToday,
                    maxDate: '28'
    });
```

please help i am wondering to set 28 as maxDate???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cna use the [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var dateToday = new Date();
  $("#date1_live").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    minDate: dateToday,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [date.getDate() <= 28]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="date1_live" />
```